# Only arrays and iterables are allowed in datatable

Tags: angular, angular5, angular6, angular-datatables

I'm trying to do a crud operation using datatable. When i click on the submit button for creation it shows me the error **Only arrays and iterables are allowed in datatable**. The console is showing the error in the component.html where the line of code is

> **component.html**

```
<table datatable [dtOptions]="dtOptions" [dtTrigger]="dtTrigger" 
class="row-border hover"> //This is where the console shows error

<tbody>
  <tr *ngFor="let person of persons">
   <td>{{ person.id }}</td>
   <td>{{ person.name}}</td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
```

> **component.ts**

```
 dtOptions: DataTables.Settings = {};
 persons: any = [];

 // We use this trigger because fetching the list of persons can be 
 quite long,
 // thus we ensure the data is fetched before rendering

 dtTrigger: any = new Subject();

 constructor(private Authentication:AuthService) { }


 ngOnInit(): void {

 this.getRolesFromServices();
this.dtOptions = {
  pagingType: 'full_numbers',
  pageLength: 4
};
this.Authentication.getRoleData()
  .map(this.extractData)
  .subscribe(persons => {
    this.persons = persons;
    // Calling the DT trigger to manually render the table
    this.dtTrigger.next();
  });

 }

 ngOnDestroy(): void {
 // Do not forget to unsubscribe the event
 this.dtTrigger.unsubscribe();
 }

 private extractData(res: Response) {
 const body = res;
 return body || {};
 }
```

I'm able to create data and it does get added but it doesn't display in the page. It gets displayed only when i refresh.

Comment: you can use _*ngIf_ if you want to check completion of fetching list of persons.
`<table datatable [dtOptions]="dtOptions" *ngIf="persons" `>

Answer (score 0):

If the `getRoleData` return **null** or empty string or in general falsy result   `extractData` will return object rather than empty array

```
private extractData(res: Response) {
 const body = res;
 return body || {}; // this cause only arrays and iterables are allowed in datatable
 }
```

just change this like like this

```
private extractData(res: Response) {
 const body = res;
 return body || [];
 }
```